# Wait until a 'Click' on a WebButton of type submit is completely finished

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I am trying to automate JIRA post configuration using VBScript. After database configuration page when I click on next button it takes several minutes to go on next URL. I want my VBScript to wait until this next button process is finished and then go to next URL.

Right now, after the next button I have made the script sleep till 2 minutes and then navigated it to next page.
But I need some replacement to `WScript.Sleep` in my code. Since this time will differ on every machine.
Following is the code I'm using right now:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("jira-setup-database-submit").Click
WScript.Sleep 120000
If (fso.FileExists("C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Application Data\JIRA\dbconfig.xml")) Then
    Call URL3
Else
    ie.Visible = 1
    MsgBox("Please enter valid Database Credential ")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cause VBA to effectively pause until the browser returns that it's ready and has finished loading.

```
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4)
    DoEvents
Loop
```